# Rails CSV Export - Adding custom field

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm building an ecommerce app in Rails. I have a method to export the Order model with shipping details. The below method works as-is but I want to add a column into the export from another model.

My order model has a product_id which joins with the product table that has the product name.  I want to add the product name. So something like order.product.name. How would I go about adding that into the below?

Here is my method in my order.rb:

```
 def self.to_csv(orders)
 wanted_columns = [:id, :shipname, :shipaddress, :shipcity, :shipstate, :shipzip]
  CSV.generate do |csv|
    csv << wanted_columns
    orders.each do |order|
    csv << order.attributes.values_at(*wanted_columns)
   end
  end
 end
```

Comment: If you have an association between the model `order` and the second model, then straightway use this line `csv << order.product.name`.

Comment: If you provide the definition of both models, then we can provide more accurate hints/solutions.

Comment: I have the association. I updated the post with more detail. Where would I place the csv line you mention? And how do I add it to the orders.attributes line?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply add it to your line, like so:

```
 def self.to_csv(orders)
   wanted_columns = [:id, :shipname, :shipaddress, :shipcity, :shipstate, :shipzip]
   CSV.generate do |csv|
     csv << wanted_columns.insert(-1, :product_name)
     orders.each do |order|
       csv << order.attributes.values_at(*wanted_columns).insert(-1, order.product.name)
     end
   end
 end
```

The `insert` method [inserts the given values before the element with the given index.](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Array.html#method-i-insert)

Negative indices count backwards from the end of the array, where -1 is the last element.

It returns the resulting array.

To simplify, in this case, this:

```
wanted_columns = [:id, :shipname, :shipaddress, :shipcity, :shipstate, :shipzip]
CSV.generate do |csv|
  csv << wanted_columns.insert(-1, :product_name)
end
```

Should behave exactly the same as:

```
CSV.generate do |csv|
  csv << [:id, :shipname, :shipaddress, :shipcity, :shipstate, :shipzip, :product_name]
end
```

The same principal applies to the array generated by:

```
order.attributes.values_at(*wanted_columns)
```

If this is not working, try the simplified example, and inspect the array for correctness prior to adding it to the array. You may additionally simplify:

```
orders.each do |order|
  csv << order.attributes.values_at(*wanted_columns).insert(-1, order.product.name)
end
```

to:

```
csv << orders.first.attributes.values_at(*wanted_columns).insert(-1, orders.first.product.name)
```

For purposes of troubleshooting...

Comment: This gives me blank columns for shipping details and then the last column has no header but has the product name.

Comment: I'm not sure why that would be, but I added some extra info for you to better understand why this should work, and hopefully determine why it does not.

Comment: I'm having the same issue as @Moosa. If I had an extra item to the headers then I get a blank value for each row and then the additional item inserted. If I don't include the additional item in the header then when I insert the item into each row there isn't a blank value. Can I add the header value after each row? Seems like that might fix it.